# asp.net core AppSettings fail when used inside hosted service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, autofac

I have the following:

```
   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac());

public class HostedServiceA : IHostedService
{
    private readonly AppSettings appSettings;

    public HostedServiceA(AppSettings appSettings)
    {
        this.appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddHttpClient();

    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

    services.AddHostedService<HostedServiceA>();
}

public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>().SingleInstance();
}
```

I am using autofac. When I try to run I am getting an exception and the program does not start: AppSettings is used inside another service as well. When I remove AppSettings from HostedService it works.

```
Unhandled Exception: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor -> ?:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService[] -> Test.MicroService.MicroServices.Web.HostedServices.RatesHostedService. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Test.MicroService.MicroServices.Web.HostedServices.RatesHostedService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Test.MicroService.MicroServices.Infrastructure.AppSettings appSettings' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Test.MicroService.MicroServices.Infrastructure.AppSettings)'.                                            at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 160
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 120
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 118
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 136
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 306
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 85
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 130                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 83
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 1041
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 871
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error says nothing about the `appsettings` file. It complains that your own custom `Test.MicroService.MicroServices.Infrastructure.AppSettings` class wasn't registered with the DI container, or can't be found

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have done it already ``` services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));```. I edited my original post and added that when I use AppSettings elsewhere it works without any problem. When I add it in the HostedService it does not work

Comment: And yet, *that's* what the error complains about. Have you configured `Autofac`? What does your `Main` look like? It should contain `.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())` *before* `.UseStartup<Startup>()`

Comment: It is registered.Edited my initial post to add the code that registers autofac

Comment: The order is wrong though

Answer (score 0):

Hosted services run on a separate thread. DI works per thread you will need to do something like this:

```
public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
            : base(consumer)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));

        }

And inside the method use like this:

using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var storageService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyService>();

}
```

Comment: There's no need for that at all, nor will it help. Configuration and DI are configured at startup. A hosted service is nothing more than a Singleton service with some special lifecycle treatment

Comment: The answer's code solves a *different* problem - how to use scoped services from a singleton service like a hosted service. It doesn't help at all if the service isn't registered in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Autofac isn't configured, or the configuration doesn't appear in the correct place.

The error complains that Autofac can't find the `Test.MicroService.MicroServices.Infrastructure.AppSettings` class even though there's a call to

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

This call will register the `AppSettings` class with the current DI container. This means that the DI container has to be configured *before* any attempt to register services.

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
    ....
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Comment: It is registered.Edited my initial post to add the code that registers autofac. As I said eveyrthing works without any issue. Problem occurs when I add AppSettings to the HostedService.

Comment: @pantonis the order is wrong though. The DI container must be added *before* the call to `UseStartup`. Otherwise the ASP.NET Core DI container is used. Adding `Autofac` won't re-registerd any services already registered with the built-in container

Comment: which order do you mean?